# Post data from mysql array into multiple txt inputs

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Im very new to the forum and have a question that has been brushed upon in several other posts but nothing gets me to where Im going. I have a populated drop down....

```
<option value="">Please Choose</option><?php echo "$col[0]"?><?php echo "$bidsList" ?></option>
```

where I would like to select from $bidsList and populate multiple text boxes with data from a mysql table. Ive placed the $col[0] in the opton value has a primary key that identifies row data from the table. The trouble Im having comes when I want to display the selected row of data. Although the array is populated with....

```
    $dbselect = "SELECT* FROM bids ORDER BY Company ASC";
```

Gathering the data from $col[0] returns nothing. Thank you in advance for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: The code for $col and $bidsList ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a SQL error

```
SELECT* FROM bids ORDER BY Company ASC
```

you see that there's no space between SELECT and the Star *